# Cannot use wine on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: xubuntu, wine, winetricks

So I just run the wine on my ubuntu 18.04.03 with

```
sudo apt install wine-stable
```

but it says:

```
Err:1 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 libasound2 i386 1.1.3-5ubuntu0.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/alsa-lib/libasound2_1.1.3-5ubuntu0.2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

How do I fix this?

Update: I tried `sudo apt-get update` and it says:

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/ideapad-laptop/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)